# What is the best SNMP Package to use with python for over 100 nodes to monitor at the same time

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I would like to request for the best python package to be able to send SNMP Request(Get,Getbulk..etc)

I am using pysnmp with multiprocessing and it is working fine for 60 nodes however when i am trying to use it for 100+ nodes with multiprocessing i could not ( I have upgraded my CPU to be sufficient enough)

my assumption the issue is either the pysnmp package or the Port itself which is 161 that can't handle to send or establish many session or send many requests at the same time.

if it is the package, which snmp package which i try to use?

Answer (score 2):

After long evaluation, it turns out **pysnmp** is the problem, because it has dependencies on other packages and SNMP MIB within Linux or Windows.
The best package is **puresnmp**, since there are no dependencies.
I have been using that packages for almost 2 months and it's working very fast for 100+ nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the plug (author of puresnmp here). It was initially developed indeed to have something independent of MIBs. There's a rewrite on the horizon which is fully asyncio and brings support for SNMPv3 as well. As it's a big architectural change, it might be a bumpy launch. Internal alpha-tests look good though. Make sure to pin your project dependencies to `<2.0` if you want to be extra-safe.